Migration from Vaadin 7 to 8
I'm trying to migrate my project from Vaadin 7.1.0 to Vaadin 8.26.0 but I'm getting error
[INFO] Downloading vaadin-compatibility-server 8.26.0 from Maven to null/.m2/repository
[ERROR] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
[ERROR] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[ERROR] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:jar:8.26.0
[ERROR]         at com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.MavenResolver.resolve(MavenResolver.java:73)
[ERROR]         at com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.VadinJarFinder.download(VadinJarFinder.java:55)
[ERROR]         at com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.VadinJarFinder.lambda$get$1(VadinJarFinder.java:22)
[ERROR]         at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
[ERROR]         at com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.VadinJarFinder.get(VadinJarFinder.java:22)
[ERROR]         at com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.Migrate.main(Migrate.java:45)
[ERROR] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:jar:8.26.0
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:387)
[ERROR]         at com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.MavenResolver.resolve(MavenResolver.java:68)
[ERROR]         ... 5 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:jar:8.26.0
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:208)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
[ERROR]         ... 6 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:jar:8.26.0
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:202)
[ERROR]         ... 7 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:pom:8.26.0 from/to central (http://central.maven.org/maven2/): central.maven.org
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
[ERROR]         ... 9 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:pom:8.26.0 from/to central (http://central.maven.org/maven2/): central.maven.org
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
[ERROR]         ... 12 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: central.maven.org
[ERROR]         at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
[ERROR]         at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1335)
[ERROR]         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1288)
[ERROR]         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1203)
[ERROR]         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:259)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:158)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:318)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:274)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
[ERROR]         at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
[ERROR]         ... 17 more
[ERROR] Migration to Vaadin 8 failed
org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\jre\bin\java -Xmx4G -Xss1024k com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.Migrate -version=8.26.0
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute (JavaCommand.java:330)
    at com.vaadin.integration.maven.Vaadin8UpgradeMojo.doExecute (Vaadin8UpgradeMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.650 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-08-01T11:11:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:8.26.0:upgrade8 (default-cli) on project quicktickets-dashboard: Problem migrating the project: Command [[
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\jre\bin\java -Xmx4G -Xss1024k com.vaadin.framework8.migrate.Migrate -version=8.26.0
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

I try adding
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>

to pom.xml but didn't work. Can please somone help me with this.
EDIT
I'm using Eclipse Version: 2024-06 (4.32.0)
Build id: 20240606-1231, Java jdk 1.8.0_361. Tried deleting all filse from repostiory same error. Tried using another version JDK same error. I'm using mvn vaadin:upgrade8 command in project terminal.

Was there any hint that adding the slf4j dependency would help? You definitely need to find out what went wrong, is there any more output?

[ERROR] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
[ERROR] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[ERROR] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-s
erver:jar:8.26.0

"compatibility-s erver" sure looks like someone's typo.

It's copy paste typo [ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:jar:8.26.0

@user1214542 Please don't amend in the comments, [edit] the question

@cfrick I did it, it's on top of question

@user1214542 No, you did not.  there is still a line-wrap.  Either the line-wrap is there and this is the error -- or this is a copy-and-paste error. Fix your question

@cfrick Is it okay now? I have edit the question and add the entire error that is occurring.

Yes, looks way better now

The log states:
java.net.UnknownHostException: central.maven.org

Which does (no longer,not) exist.  This URL is either in your project or in your ~/.m2.

I encountered this problem while working on 2 projects the first was vaadin 14 and the other was with the latest Vaadin 24 .
The problem is related to your .Vaadin folder located  /Users/..../.Vaadin
you have to delete the .Vaadin folder so you can download the new dependencies
EDIT :
You might want to save a backup for .Vaadin folder

Thank you for the response. If you mean the Vaadin folder in  C:/Users//.m2/repository/com/vaadin, I tried deleting it, but the same error still occurs.

I have the .vaadin folder outside .m2 but they are both in the same folder.    does your folder have a node module inside ?

Still same Error

Okey lets Try this : accourding to Vaadin  the version 8.26.0 is the the most stable release  could you change it and delete your dependeies folder including .vaadin (also note your SLF4J version is failing to load a logger implementation) . then use Run mvn dependency:purge-local-repository to remove and re-download dependencies.

Try it and nothing, same errors

V8 does not use node. So deleting ~/.vaadin may or may not be the reason, but for sure it is not due to node modules or node binaries there.
